# Zigbee device not responding

Tags: zigbee

I am sending one file from Zig bee coordinator to end device.
While sending file I am sending it in chunks of 64 bytes plus header which forms packet of 71 bytes.
Now since the size of the file is too large about 2000 packets are to be transmitted.

The problem is I can successfully transmit few of the packets and then the device doesn't send any response.The no. of packets that can be successfully transmitted is about 90 and this is not fixed it varies from some 20s to 90s and not more than that.

So can anyone please tell me what exactly is causing this thing to happen...

Comment: Your question is a little vague... what chip are you talking about? Have you tried with a network sniffer to see what is happening? Can you debug the end device in some way? Is there a network interference? Can you put the devices closer?

Comment: What baud rate are you using?  Have you enabled hardware flow control to ensure that you're only sending to the radio when it's ready to receive bytes?

Comment: baud rate 115200 and no hardware flow control used.

Answer (score 0):

try reducing the size of packet from 64 bytes to 32 bytes...
I was facing same problem and this solved it.